# Files not found while searching through directory?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

```
int d = 0;
foreach (string curFile in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("Content/img/"))
{
    tiles[d] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(curFile);
    d++;
}
```

I have the above code, which is supposed to search through the directory, `img`, and assign each file to the `tiles[]` array. However, it seems to be searching for `.xnb` files rather than `.png`'s that I have the images saved as. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

[`Directory.GetFiles(string path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) is going to return the full path of *every* file in that directory. Since  you want only the .png files, you should use  [`Directory.GetFiles(string path, string searchPattern)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) which takes a second argument that specifies a search pattern.

```
Directory.GetFiles("Content/img/", ".png");
```

Also, since you're using an array for `tiles`, I forsee your code having issues, as you probably don't know *how many* textures you're going to load from the directory.  Instead, I suggest you use a `List<T>`:

```
var tiles = new List<Texture2D>();
foreach (var imagePath in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("Content/img/", ".png"))
{
    tiles.Add( Content.Load<Texture2D>(imagePath) );
}
```

You could even get a little LINQ-crazy and do it in "one" line:

```
var tiles = Directory.GetFiles("Content/img/", ".png")
            .Select( Content.Load<Texture2D> );
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't work... Now I'm getting the error that "tiles" is null, I'd assume it's not finding any of the images?

Comment: Did you miss the line `var tiles = new List<Texture2D>();` ?  You should *really* try and understand what all error messages mean. It means that the list you're trying to *add* the images to has not been created - it doesn't say *anything* about images being there or not.

Comment: the context matters... and this is a XNA related question... the content manager never will load a png that way

Answer (score 1):

The content manager in Xna works with precompiled xnb files.

So you have to search for the xnb files, remove the extension adn make the path relative to the content manger root.

```
var tiles = new List<Texture2D>();
foreach (var imagePath in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("Content/img/", ".xnb"))
{
    var xnaPath = Path.Combine( "Content/img",
                                 Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imagePath));

    tiles.Add( Content.Load<Texture2D>(xnaPath) );
}
```

if your content manager root folder is "content", then you shoould combine with the "img" folder, not the "content/img"